# VHDL Signal Assignment Confusion

Tags: vhdl, hdl

I was studying VHDL and came across a question for which I could not find an answer. I understand the below example and why the result is 7:

```
architecture SIGN of EXAMPLE is
  signal TRIGGER, RESULT: integer := 0; 
  signal signal1: integer :=1;
  signal signal2: integer :=2;
  signal signal3: integer :=3;
begin

  process 
  begin
    wait on TRIGGER;
    signal1 <= signal2;
    signal2 <= signal1 + signal3;
    signal3 <= signal2;
    RESULT <= signal1 + signal2 + signal3;
  end process;

end SIGN;
```

However, what happens if I put signal1 in the sensitivity list? Or all of the signals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if a sensitivity list is created for the process, then the `wait on TRIGGER` statement must be removed or commented out, since a process with sensitivity list can't also have `wait` statements.

If `signal1` is the process sensitivity list, then the process is initially run and then re-run as long as there are changes to the `signal1`.

The values after default assing, or based on assign in process run, are for `signal1`, `signal2`, `signal3`, and `RESULT`:

```
Default.:  1,  2,  3,  0
First...:  2,  4,  2,  6
Re-run 1:  4,  4,  4,  8
Re-run 2:  4,  8,  4, 12
```

Remember that signal assign does not take effect until after the process has finished, based on the delta cycle simulation model.

Since there is no change in `signal1` between re-run 1 and 2, then the process is not run any more, and the value of `RESULT` is thus 12, as from the last run.

If `signal1` and `signal2` are in the process sensitivity list, then each process run will alter one of the signals, thus the process will continue to rerun until the simulator delta cycle iteration limit is reached or an out of range value will occur for the `integer` data type, resulting in no further change of the value.

Answer (score 3):

You're waving your hands without showing a complete example and what changes you are proposing.

At present, why isn't RESULT = 0?

Why aren't you simulating all this?

```
entity example is
end entity;

architecture SIGN of EXAMPLE is
signal TRIGGER, RESULT: integer := 0; 
signal signal1: integer :=1;
signal signal2: integer :=2;
signal signal3: integer :=3;
begin
process 
begin
wait on TRIGGER;
signal1 <= signal2;
signal2 <= signal1 + signal3;
signal3 <= signal2;
RESULT <= signal1 + signal2 + signal3;
end process;
monitor:
    process(RESULT)
    begin
        report "RESULT = " & integer'image(RESULT);
    end process;
end SIGN;
```

> sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 0

```
entity example is
end entity;

architecture SIGN of EXAMPLE is
signal TRIGGER, RESULT: integer := 0; 
signal signal1: integer :=1;
signal signal2: integer :=2;
signal signal3: integer :=3;
begin
process (signal1)
begin
-- wait on TRIGGER;
signal1 <= signal2;
signal2 <= signal1 + signal3;
signal3 <= signal2;
RESULT <= signal1 + signal2 + signal3;
end process;
monitor:
    process(RESULT)
    begin
        report "RESULT = " & integer'image(RESULT);
    end process;
end SIGN;
```

> sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 0
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 6
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 8
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 12

```
entity example is
end entity;

architecture SIGN of EXAMPLE is
signal TRIGGER, RESULT: integer := 0; 
signal signal1: integer :=1;
signal signal2: integer :=2;
signal signal3: integer :=3;
begin
process (signal1, signal2, signal3)
begin
-- wait on TRIGGER;
signal1 <= signal2;
signal2 <= signal1 + signal3;
signal3 <= signal2;
RESULT <= signal1 + signal2 + signal3;
end process;
monitor:
    process(RESULT)
    begin
        report "RESULT = " & integer'image(RESULT);
    end process;
end SIGN;
```

> sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 0
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 6
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 8
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 12
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 16
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 24
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 32
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 48
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 64
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 96
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 128
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 192
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 256
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 384
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 512
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 768
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 1024
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 1536
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 2048
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 3072
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 4096
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 6144
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 8192
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 12288
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 16384
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 24576
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 32768
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 49152
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 65536
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 98304
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 131072
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 196608
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 262144
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 393216
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 524288
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 786432
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 1048576
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 1572864
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 2097152
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 3145728
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 4194304
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 6291456
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 8388608
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 12582912
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 16777216
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 25165824
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 33554432
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 50331648
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 67108864
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 100663296
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 134217728
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 201326592
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 268435456
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 402653184
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 536870912
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 805306368
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 1073741824
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 1610612736
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = -2147483648
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = -1073741824
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 0
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = -2147483648
>   sign.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): RESULT = 0

And adding `RESULT` and `TRIGGER` to the sensitivity list gives the same answer.  Can you tell why?

And the value rollover actually reveals a bug in this VHDL implementation.

IEEE Std 1076-2008, 5.2.3 Integer types, 5.2.3.1 General, paragraph 7/ -1993, 3.1.2 Integer types, paragraph 7 (note 9.2 reference is 7.2 in -1993):

> The same arithmetic operators are predefined for all integer types (see 9.2). It is an error if the execution of such an operation (in particular, an implicit conversion) cannot deliver the correct result (that is, if the value corresponding to the mathematical result is not a value of the integer type).

"It is an error" leaves no room for not having the correct result.  The simulation should have had an error for a "+" operation result exceeding INTEGER'HIGH.  It's a failure to test bounds for the subtype of signals declared as type INTEGER.